# Cohomology of a maping torus

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

Let $M^d$ be a mapping torus, which is fiber bundle over $S^1$ with fiber $N^{d-1}$. Assume $M^d$ is orientable and closed.
Can we express the cohomology $H^n(M^d,Z)$ in terms of
 the cohomology $H^n(N^{d-1},Z)$? Whether there is simple result for mapping torus?

Comment: Your question is a reasonable one, but is a standard exercise in algebraic topology.  As such, it's not 'research level', and I'm going to vote to close.  I think it would get a good answer at math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: I join the vote. Just as a hint, use Mayer--Vietoris.

Answer (score 2):

See example 2.48 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.

Comment: https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf (page 151)